# Import header file from iOS static library into watchOS static library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, watchos

I have written static library for iOS and added in the same project static library for watchOS for which I want to be pretty same as iOS one.

I tried to add into watchOS header from iOS static library. But then it start to complain while it builds that **UIViewController** and **UIApplicationState** is unknown types.
But into that header I already done this:

```
#if !TARGET_OS_WATCHOS
- (void)track:(UIViewController *_Nonnull)controller;
- (void)updateFirstSessionWith: (UIApplicationState) state;
#endif
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper research I found a really good [example](https://github.com/bishalg/Lister-for-watchOS-iOS-and-OS-X-) for it and resolve problem.

I have had extra 'OS' in if statement.

```
#if !TARGET_OS_WATCH
- (void)track:(UIViewController *_Nonnull)controller;
- (void)updateFirstSessionWith: (UIApplicationState) state;
#endif
```